# Subquery in select after group-by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I want to display the name of data types, which were used at least 10 times throughout the database, with the number of different tables they were used in, ordered by the latter. While tinkering, I got to this point:

```
select data_type, count(distinct table_name) "count"
from all_tab_cols
group by data_type
having count(*) >= 10
order by "count" desc;
```

with output

```
VARCHAR2 1920
NUMBER   1435
...
```

which is wrong, because views, etc. are included and I only got 125 tables in the database.
However if I try

```
select data_type, (select count(distinct t.table_name)
                   from all_tables t
                   where t.table_name in table_name) "count"
from all_tab_cols
group by data_type
having count(*) >= 10
order by "count" desc;
```

I get

```
LONG         125
SDO_GEOMETRY 125
... and so on
```

which is also wrong. Clearly this is because of the subquery, more specific the `where` clause. I thought that `table_name` contains only the table names for the current group? Is there anything wrong with my thinking? How would you solve this?

FWIW, this is homework, so some rough pointers suffice.
We are using a clone of the internet movie data base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd join `all_tab_columns` to `all_tables` - that will filter out the non-table information:

```
select data_type, count(distinct table_name) "count"
from all_tab_cols
inner join all_tables using (owner, table_name)
group by data_type
having count(*) >= 10
order by "count" desc;
```

I've used a "natural join" here (`using ...`) because, well, it was a lot easier :)

Comment: I had thought about it at a point but dropped it for some reason.
This is perfect! But could you explain why my solution doesn't seem to work?

Comment: It may be the `where t.table_name in table_name` in the subquery. I can't quite figure out what it's doing so naturally I suspect it :)

Comment: I had the hope that it would let only those tables pass, which where referenced by the data_type, thus having a column in table_names within the select statement, so I could test for it with `in` within a subquery. Doesn't seem to work and is much uglier than what you proposed.